# CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding deprecated on OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, macos-carbon, osx-elcapitan

In the latest version of OS X (10.11 El Capitan), [CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayModeCopyPixelEncoding) function was deprecated and there is no information on the documentation regarding which function should be used instead. 
I'm trying to get information about the display BPP using Quartz Display Services API. Are there any other way to get this information from a given CGDisplayID in El Capitan?

Comment: I don't think you really mean "Carbon", since Quartz Display Services is not part of Carbon.

Comment: You are right, I meant to say Quartz Display Services API

Comment: any luck in looking for replacement?